# SQLite Database editor for App Development

Tags: sqlite, maui, sqlite-net

I am working with a SQLite3 Database in my .NET MAUI App. The App is running on **Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33)**-Emulator right now.

Right now, I am doing my SELCT-Statements to verify my stored data directly in the adb command probmpt (VS > Tools > Android > Android Adb Command Prompt...).

This command prompt is not very comfortable for me as it doesn't even provide a history of the commands I executed. Also, I always have to login first as "adb root" then run "adb shell" and within that connect to my SQLite3 database (sqlite3 /data/user/0/com.companyname.myapp/files/MyDatabaseSQLite.db3).

Is there a Database Editor I can use in combination with App-Development and connect to my database which is actually running in my Emulator. In case there is no Database Editor is there anything that at least provides some history for the commands I executed?

Comment: Why dont you use the Database Inpector ?https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database

Comment: Not an answer but maybe you could use EF along with and maybe editor would not be needed: https://medium.com/@taublast/entity-framework-with-code-first-migrations-in-net-maui-3efbdb765592. Google for "EF compiled queries chapsas" after that.

Comment: @Q.u.a.n.gL. - I am working with Visual Studio 2022 and Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33)-Emulator. I can't see the option described there neither in VS-Menus nor in the Android Device Manager

Comment: Not sure I understand your setup, but maybe https://dbeaver.io

Comment: Try SQLite Editor for Android

Comment: @MarkSetchell - My setup is Visual Studio 2022 with a .NET MAUI App Project running on an Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33)-Emulator, so the database is stored somewhere within the Emulator. Therefore, I would have to access the DB directly inside the emulator or do something like ```adb pull /data/user/0/com.companyname.myapp/files/DatabaseSQLite.db3 D:\Databases``` to download the db3-File and play with it then.

Then I can also use your recommended app dbeaver.io. Bit complicated though as I would have to download the db3-File with adb pull everytime there was a change in my db

Comment: There are numerous SQLite tools available, but all require you to extract the files with adb first